# Birational equivalence of cubic with a Weierstrass form

Tags: elliptic-curves

I want to convert the cubic $x^3 + 3y^3 - 11z^3 = 0$ to Weierstrass form (to find its rank) so I tried to follow the [suggestion from Timothy](http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/math/8301/Cubic-curve-in-Weierstrass-form): I found three points $(2:1:1),(28:-19:5),(-537656:443213:212645)$ on the curve and used a linear change of variables to map them to $(1:0:0),(0:1:0),(0:0:1)$ then I dehomogenized and set $y' = xy$ then homogenized that to get $1330 x'^3 - 252013629 x'^2 z' = y'^2 z' - 2352637000 y' z'^2 - 56454 x' y' z'$. It doesn't seem to be birationally equivalent to what I started with (due to the rehomogenization), $(1:0:0)$ isn't a zero anymore (but $(1:0:9480240/201019314751)$ is).

So if anyone could tell me where I went wrong, or suggest a different technique or reference on how to convert elliptic curves into Weierstrass form that would be a big help. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer is most likely too late, but here it is just in case others find it useful. The general procedure to transform a genus $1$ cubic projective curve into Weierstrass form is outlined in Silverman/Tate "Rational points on elliptic curves", Chapter I, Section 3, pages 22-23.

Some software packages can do this for you. For instance, Magma can do it. [Magma has an online calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) (which is free to use as long as the calculation does not go over 60 seconds). Here is some code that will take your curve and output a Weierstrass form, a minimal model for the curve, and the rank:

```
PP<x,y,z>:=ProjectiveSpace(Rationals(),2);
C:=Curve(PP,x^3+3*y^3-11*z^3);
P0:=C![2,1,1];
E, phi:=EllipticCurve(C,P0);
Em, psi:= MinimalModel(E);
E;
Em;
Rank(Em);
```

The output that we obtain is:

```
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 7776/25*x^2 + 20155392/625*x -
181398528/625 over Rational Field
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + y = x^3 - 7351 over Rational Field
1
```

So your curve is given by $y^2+y=x^3-7351$ and its Mordell-Weil rank is $1$.